# UI goes blank for a second when bringing up Modal Pop Up Extender

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net repeater and it has an edit button which brings up a Modal Pop Up extender (MPE) where a user enters modified values and then submits the changes in the MPE. When the MPE appears after the Edit button in the repeater is clicked - the whole page is reloaded - because the screen goes blank for a second and then gets re-populated. Is this the Page_load firing due to the action in the repeater? If so, can I prevent this. Here is the related code:

aspx page:

```
<td><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgBtEdit" ToolTip="Edit" AlternateText="Edit" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Id")%>' ImageUrl="~/css/images/icon.png"/></td>
```

Code Behind:

```
 protected void REPEATER_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
          if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
            {  
               MPExtender.Show();            
            }
        }

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                List<T> lst = GetList();              
                REPEATER.DataSource = lst;
                REPEATER.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're using a repeater, an ImageButton and a MPE in an MVC application?

Comment: @Dismissile - Should I not? What will you use. Thanks

Comment: MVC does not support the traditional server controls that ASP.net WebForms uses. You use traditional HTML markup with client side scripting languages like jQuery, etc.

Comment: Server controls that do not require ViewState to fully function will work in MVC, but anything that requires PostBack to work properly will not.